# After installation interrupted file size turned to 0 KB

Tags: windows, windows-10, installation

I was installing Anaconda 5.3, while installation was inprogress my PC turned off now the same file is showing size 0 KB. Original size was 1.8 GB.

When I click on install, error prompt `The parameter is incorrect`.

How can I get my file back? because I do not have that much data to download the file again.

Comment: Short answer: You need to download it again.

Comment: @DavidPostill - Thank you for your input. You can write it as answer with little more detail.